# UIWebView with NavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview

Imagine there is a list of posts and if you click a postItem, then a detailed post view shows up. For example,

**/index**

`[post1, post2, post3 ...]`

post1 is clicked

**/posts/1**

`Hello! I am a post!`

Also, the website that will be included inside the UIWebView is a single page web app, which makes things a little tricky. Since the webapp *renders* parts instead of `redirecting`, navigation doesn't necessarily make another web request. For regular websites that make a new url request for every navigation, I can use either `webViewDidStartLoad` or `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`, having one ViewController per webpage. A naive solution for my case would be forcing a fresh redirect for every navigation, using `window.location = url`.

However, that loses the performance boost coming from rendering specific parts. A better way to do it is attaching a navigationItem such as `title` and `back button` dynamically when the user moves away from the index page. The problem is, **how do I detect whether the user moved to /posts/1 from /index if I am not doing a full redirect?**

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For your last idea to bind the title and back button you could use the following, but you will need to modify the website code.

You can communicate with your native controller from the webview using a custom protocol / scheme of url.

The idea is to make a call like `window.location = 'myapp://thisismyaction/thisisanarg'` when you need to update.

Once the call is made you intercept it with `-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`.

In this method you parse your request to detect if it start with myapp:// and you parse the line to get your action and your args. The syntax is up to you like regular queryString or else as in my example. You do your update and the title based on what you parse and you return NO to prevent loading a non-existant URL.

To make sur that this call is only happening from webview and not a browser, you could inject some javascript object when you webview finish loading with `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method from the webview, and check if the object is defined before making the call from the javascript.